# Sublime - duplicate multiple whole lines, not just selection

Tags: sublimetext3, shortcut

The `duplicate_line` shortcut in sublime, only duplicate the selections, when select across multiple lines.

How to duplicate the whole lines?

For example, I select last 3 chars of line 1, and whole line 2, then first 2 chars of line 3.
Aka. 3 lines selected, how to duplicate the whole 3 lines, not just the chars selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Duplicate lines" only duplicates what is selected (unless nothing is selected, in which case it duplicates the whole line). If you have lines partially selected, first do **`Selection → Expand Selection to Line`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> on Mac) to make sure the entire lines are selected, then do "Duplicate Lines".

Please note that if the last line is already fully selected and the cursor is on the beginning of the *next line*, that next line will also get selected. I advise you to play around with different kinds of selections to get a feel for how "Expand Selection to Line" works.

Comment: I think probably most user want to expand automatically, and duplicate whole lines, most of the time. Hope sublime can support an additional shortcut to make it easy.

Comment: @EricWang I suppose the expected action could go either way, depending on the user. There is no plain `duplicate` command, so I suppose the thinking goes that if you only have a partial line selected, you did that for a reason and only want to duplicate that, since there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a macro for this and assign a hotkey.

Create the file `duplicate_full_line.sublime-macro` with this text in it:

```
duplicate_full_line.sublime-macro
[
    {"command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line" }},
    {"command": "duplicate_line" }
]
```

And add the keybinding to the file `Default (<your OS>).sublime-keymap`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+d"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/duplicate_full_line.sublime-macro"} },
```

You may want to bind the original `duplicate-line` command as well:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+d"], "command": "duplicate_line" },
```